# Check if date is in the past Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, validation, date

All,
I'm using the jQuery UI for the date picker. I'm trying to check with javascript though that the date the user has entered is in the past. Here is my form code:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="event_date" class="datepicker">
```

Then how would I check this with Javascript to make sure it isn't a date in the past? Thanks

Answer (score 143, accepted):

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker().change(evt => {
  var selectedDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
  var now = new Date();
  now.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  if (selectedDate < now) {
    console.log("Selected date is in the past");
  } else {
    console.log("Selected date is NOT in the past");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="event_date" class="datepicker">
```

Comment: The one-liner: `if ($('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate') < new Date) { ... }`. Parentheses can be omitted when invoking a function with the `new` keyword.

Comment: You can probably skip the ```now``` variable. by using ```(selectedDate.getTime() < Date.now())```

Comment: @MiguelTrias: Of course. This makes it just a little bit clearer for the reader.

Comment: If you're just looking at the date (without time) then you should probably compare against the start of today like so `var now = ( new Date() ).setHours(0,0,0,0);`

Comment: Why use setHours?

Comment: @Abhinav: explained by the comment immediately above yours: OP asked for "date", not "time".

Comment: Why can't we just use `$('#datepicker').val()` instead of `$('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate')`? Looks like it's working for me.

Comment: @IvanYurchenko: `.val()` returns a string, literally what's in the `<input>`. `.datepicker('getDate')` returns a `Date` object.

Answer (score 16):

```
var datep = $('#datepicker').val();

if(Date.parse(datep)-Date.parse(new Date())<0)
{
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply convert the dates into milliseconds and subtract

```
let givenDate1 =   new Date("10/21/2001")  // Past Date
let givenDate2 =   new Date("10/21/2050") // future Date
```

If diff is **positive**, then given date is **PAST**

```
 let diff = new Date().getTime() - givenDate1.getTime();
  if (diff > 0) {
     console.log('Given Date givenDate1 is in Past');
   }
```

If diff is **negative**, then given date is **Future**

```
 let diff = new Date().getTime() - givenDate2.getTime();
  if (diff < 0) {
     console.log('Given Date givenDate2 is in Future');
   }
```

Comment: Do you really need new Date($.now()) ? isn't it the same with new Date() ?

Comment: @AlexandruEftimie, yeah you are right, both are same. no need for doing new Date($.now())

Comment: +1. If you don't want to treat today as being in the past then instead of `.getTime()` you can use `.setHours(0,0,0,0)`.

Answer (score 2):

To make the answer more re-usable for things other than just the datepicker change function you can create a prototype to handle this for you.

```
// safety check to see if the prototype name is already defined
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    if (!this.prototype[name]) {
        this.prototype[name] = func;
        return this;
    }
};
Date.method('inPast', function () {
    return this < new Date($.now());// the $.now() requires jQuery
});

// including this prototype as using in example
Date.method('addDays', function (days) {
    var date = new Date(this);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + (days));    
    return date;
});
```

If you dont like the safety check you can use the conventional way to define prototypes:

```
Date.prototype.inPast = function(){
    return this < new Date($.now());// the $.now() requires jQuery
}
```

Example Usage

```
var dt = new Date($.now());
var yesterday = dt.addDays(-1);
var tomorrow = dt.addDays(1);
console.log('Yesterday: ' + yesterday.inPast());
console.log('Tomorrow: ' + tomorrow.inPast());
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use isPast(date) method from date-fns library.

```
import { isPast } from 'date-fns'
console.log(new Date('1991-06-17'));
// returns true.
console.log(new Date('2191-06-17'));
// returns false.
```

More info about the method:
https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/isPast

Answer (score -11):

```
function isPrevDate() {
    alert("startDate is " + Startdate);
    if(Startdate.length != 0 && Startdate !='') {
        var start_date = Startdate.split('-');
        alert("Input date: "+ start_date);
        start_date=start_date[1]+"/"+start_date[2]+"/"+start_date[0];
        alert("start date arrray format " + start_date);
        var a = new Date(start_date);
        //alert("The date is a" +a);
        var today = new Date();
        var day = today.getDate();
        var mon = today.getMonth()+1;
        var year = today.getFullYear();
        today = (mon+"/"+day+"/"+year);
        //alert(today);
        var today = new Date(today);
        alert("Today: "+today.getTime());
        alert("a : "+a.getTime());
        if(today.getTime() > a.getTime() )
        {
            alert("Please select Start date in range");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where comes the var Startdate from?