# Calendar validation for previous date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to be able to add a validation (alertbox) if the user selects a previous date from the calendar.

Today's date is `13/11/2015`. If the user was to select `12/11/2015` it should display an alert box saying `"Please enter a valid date."`

I've looked online and can't seem to find anything to do with this.

**Can this be done with javascript?**

```
<input type="date" id="leaveDate">
<script>
     alert("Please enter a valid date.");
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried `Datepicker()` from jQuery UI ?

Comment: A simple Google search brought me this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305259/check-if-date-is-in-the-past-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Considering you want a solution in javascript, here is something you can try with onchange function.

```
<input type='date' onchange="validateDate()" id='mydate'></input>

<script>
function validateDate() {
    var userdate = new Date(document.getElementById("mydate").value).toJSON().slice(0,10);
    var today = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);
    if(userdate < today){
      alert('Your message');
    }
}
</script>
```

PS: Replace 'Your message' with the text you want to display.

Comment: When i select todays date. it gives me an alert box? why?

Comment: Oops..!! Thats because my solution is comparing current date and time rather than just date. Let me update the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want the user to select the past dates then I would suggest you to disable it like this using the datepicker:

```
$("#mydate").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

However if you are intended to do the alert message approach then the thread: [Check if date is in the past Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305259/check-if-date-is-in-the-past-javascript) is doing what you are looking for.

Comment: Downvoter, please care to leave a comment! :)

Comment: it should display an alert box saying "Please enter a valid date." . not what OP asked :/

Comment: @Hacketo:- I am aware of what OP has asked for. Infact thats why I answered by saying `If you dont want the user to select the past dates` since alert message is just to restrict user from entering the past dates. Using alert seems not very productive to me.

Comment: I also downvoted for educational purposes, sorry .