# Angular 2 - Compare date in an array filter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This will get me current time in seconds:

```
let currentTimeInSeconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
```

I have an array with the object `expirationDate`, it returns that information in seconds. I can get the bills that expired, however, I'd like to filter out the bills that are expiring **today**.

```
this.ExpiringTodayBills = this.UnpaidDuebills.filter(bills => bills.paid === false && bills.expirationDate = currentTimeInSeconds);
```

The above code doesn't work because current time changes constantly due to hours, minute, seconds and milliseconds.

How would I be able to compare if expirationDate = today, regardless of the time?

**Edit:** This is an example of a bill

**name:** Test bill

**paid:** false

**expirationDate:** 1535598000 (which means August 30, 2018 3:00:00 AM)

**amount:** 231.33

Comment: Have you tried this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305259/check-if-date-is-in-the-past-javascript

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera and how would I be able to do that inside a filter? Granted that I can do that with `currentTimeInSeconds`, but what about `bills.expirationDate` that is coming out from inside the filter?

Comment: Do you get a timestamp on `bill.expirationDate `?

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera nope, regular current time in seconds.

Comment: Can you please post some bills in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
isExpiringToday(expirationDate) {
  const start = new Date();
  start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  const end = new Date();
  end.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);

  const expiryDateTimeStamp = expirationDate * 1000;

  return (expiryDateTimeStamp > start && expiryDateTimeStamp < end);
}

this.ExpiringTodayBills = this.UnpaidDuebills
  .filter(bills => !bills.paid && this.isExpiringToday(bills.expirationDate));
```

You can test this by opening the Browser Dev Tools, going to the console and doing this:

```
function isToday(expiryDateTimeStamp) {
    const start = new Date();
    start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    const end = new Date();
    end.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);

    return (expiryDateTimeStamp > start && expiryDateTimeStamp < end);
}

var newDate = new Date();
isToday(newDate.getTime())  // true
```

Comment: How would it know if the bill expires today? It gets all the expired bills, but I wanna cherry pick the ones that expire today.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I feel like this is very close to the answer, but unfortunately it returns false to every date, including the ones expiring today.

Comment: Works for me. I swear :P

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through your data and convert your `expirationDate` from `currentTimeInSeconds` to a `date`. The library `moment.js` can be helpful. 
Next, you can do:

```
this.ExpiringTodayBills = this.UnpaidDuebills.filter(bills => bills.paid === false && bills.expirationDate = today);
```

```js
const today = moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY');
console.log(today);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```