# Check if dates in array contains a date later than the current date

Tags: javascript

I have an array of date object:

```js
const dates = [
  '2021-11-01T19:49:08.678Z',
  '2021-11-01T20:13:27.954Z',
  '2021-08-31T19:15:16.452Z',
  '1983-04-16T20:18:39.802Z',
  '2022-02-02T20:26:14.992Z',
  '2022-02-02T20:30:36.374Z',
  '2022-02-02T20:33:09.266Z',
  '2022-02-02T20:35:34.615Z',
  '2022-02-02T20:44:19.131Z',
  '2022-02-02T20:48:17.274Z'
]
```

I want to check if at least one of the dates inside the array is later than the current date (if there is any date which has not reached yet return `true`, if all of them past return `false`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if date is in the past Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305259/check-if-date-is-in-the-past-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to parse each date and the `>` operator to check whether the date is later than the current date.

```js
const arr = [
  '2021-11-01T19:49:08.678Z',
  '2021-11-01T20:13:27.954Z',
  '2021-08-31T19:15:16.452Z',
  '1983-04-16T20:18:39.802Z',
  '2022-02-02T20:26:14.992Z',
  '2022-02-02T20:30:36.374Z',
  '2022-02-02T20:33:09.266Z',
  '2022-02-02T20:35:34.615Z',
  '2022-02-02T20:44:19.131Z',
  '2022-02-02T20:48:17.274Z'
]

const hasPassed = arr.some(e => new Date(e) > new Date);
console.log(hasPassed);
```

Comment: This is not working... it only compares dates not time..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for this:

```js
const dates = [
    '2021-11-01T19:49:08.678Z',
    '2021-11-01T20:13:27.954Z',
    '2021-08-31T19:15:16.452Z',
    '1983-04-16T20:18:39.802Z',
    '2022-02-02T20:26:14.992Z',
    '2022-02-02T20:30:36.374Z',
    '2022-02-02T20:33:09.266Z',
    '2022-02-02T20:35:34.615Z',
    '2022-02-02T20:44:19.131Z',
    '2022-02-02T20:48:17.274Z',
];

// If they're strings
console.log(dates.some(d => new Date(d).valueOf() > Date.now()));

const asDates = dates.map(d => new Date(d));
// If they're actual Date objects
console.log(asDates.some(d => d.valueOf() > Date.now()));

const dates2 = [
    '1983-04-16T20:18:39.802Z',
];

console.log(dates2.some(d => new Date(d).valueOf() > Date.now()));

const asDates2 = dates2.map(d => new Date(d));
console.log(asDates2.some(d => d.valueOf() > Date.now()));
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) should be sufficient for your problem I suppose

```js
const referenceDate = new Date();
console.log([
  `2021-11-01T19:49:08.678Z`,
  `2021-11-01T20:13:27.954Z`,
  `2021-08-31T19:15:16.452Z`,
  `1983-04-16T20:18:39.802Z`,
  `2022-02-02T20:26:14.992Z`,
  `2022-02-02T20:30:36.374Z`,
  `2022-02-02T20:33:09.266Z`,
  `2022-02-02T20:35:34.615Z`,
  `2022-02-02T20:44:19.131Z`,
  `2022-02-02T20:48:17.274Z`
].find(d => new Date(d) > referenceDate)
)
```